# Calculating the trace for an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt5})/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension. For every $\alpha \in L$ we define the K-linear map $\phi_{\alpha}: L \rightarrow L$, $x \rightarrow \alpha x$.

I am trying to calculate the trace of $[\phi_{\alpha}]$.

Here is an example:
Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt5})/\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\alpha=\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}$

With some calculation one can find out that $\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt10}{2}$

Thus we get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt10)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt10) $

Thus we get the basis $\{1,\sqrt2,\sqrt10,\sqrt20\}$

The onl step left is the calculation of the matrix representation of $\phi_{\alpha}$:

$\alpha \times 1= \frac{1}{2} \times \sqrt2 +\frac{1}{2} \times \sqrt10$

$\alpha \times \sqrt2=1+ \frac{1}{2} \times \sqrt20$

$\alpha \times \sqrt10=5+ \frac{1}{2} \times \sqrt10$

$\alpha \times \sqrt20=5\times \sqrt2+ \frac{1}{2} \times \sqrt20$

So we get $[\phi_{\alpha}]:$

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 5 & 0\\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 5\\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0\\
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite:$$\alpha \sqrt{10}=5+ \frac12 \sqrt{20}$$
and
$$\alpha\sqrt{20}=5\sqrt2+ \sqrt{10}.$$

Comment: The trace is therefore $0,$ which you could compute more quickly as the sum of the four conjugates. There is indeed no monomial of degree 3 in the minimal polynomial $(x)=(x^2-3)^2-5.$ This second approach amounts to calculate the matrix in the base $(1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3).$ You find the companion matrix of $P.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh I did micalculate as it seems. Thank you for the hint with the conjugates. But calculating the matrix and then the trace of the matrix would still be correct, right?

Comment: Yes, both methods do.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops there was a $P$ missing in front of my "$(x)=(x^2-3)^2-5$".